# How to achieve this view using UIStackview?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uistackview

I want to use `UIStackview`, for making the below UI. The Problem I am facing to give un even space while using `UIStackViews`.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like a good candidate for a stackview layout.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup that we can not make this using stackview?

Comment: Not really.  There are better ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is possible through `stackview` in a feasible way. If you want uneven size or spaces - one can set the distribution `fill-proportional` or alignment to `center`  and apply single constraint - for space, for height  or width.

The point is that using `stackview` we do things with least number of constraints.

The below UI has 11 constraints of which 4 are used for stackview position and size.

**My results are:** For most Design, while using `stackview` we don't need to apply constraint for internal elements. But for some case like this we can still use `stackview` and get the benifits by using very minimum amount of contraints. We still have all the power of autolayout while using `stackview`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, but I achieved it earlier. You posted first acceptable so here your credit goes up.

Comment: Thanks Sandy. Time has come where choice between auto-layout and stackview would easily be stackview. Stackview is not compatible with iOS 8, But thats not the issue now, almost all the devices have shifted above iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are not pinning the elements to each other and their parent view? UIStackView would not be my first option in this case.

Comment: That means we can go with stackview only for specific UI?

Comment: I would say specific layout, rather than specific UI.